# Preact CLI CSS Modules

Tags: preact

The [Preact CLI](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli) claims it supports `CSS Modules` out of the box. So this is what I tried; Given 2 files `index.js` and `index.module.scss` in the same folder I tried this:

**index.js**

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import styles from './index.module.scss';

export default class Layout extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(styles);
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.module.scss**

```
.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The `console.log` statement prints `{}`, the `class` attribute in the HTML is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Oh, to install this stuff I just did

```
preact create default my-project
yarn add -D node-sass sass-loader
```

Comment: can you try importing styles from a css files instead?

import styles from './index.module.css';

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this with a fresh setup and `CSS` files but it did not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I found the issue. `preact cli` forces you to put your components in the `src/components` folder or css modules won't work. Now it does.

For completion, it's possible to make CSS Modules work outside the /components folder: https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/522#issuecomment-370835370

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem, except i NEED css modules to work when importing from outside of /components directory, because i am importing from node_modules/ How can i achieve that?

Comment: @DanilaAlpatov it's possible: https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/522#issuecomment-370835370

Answer (score 3):

@Lukas i voted your answer up caused it's true, but the actually way i believe preact-cli wants us to use it is by adding all reusable styles into `style/index.css` file. That is added to the `index.html` in the build and use can reference your style with normal css reference `<Comp style='my-style' ....`